# Coger el valor de un id HTML con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Algo tengo que estar haciendo mal pero no veo el que. Tengo una lista de divs y quiero que cuando hagan click en un elemento de la lista me coja su id. Actualmente tengo esto pero no consigo que funcione.

```js
(function($) {

  function selectParams() {
    $(this).click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      console.log(id);
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-column" id="first-column">
  <li id="WE"><div><span>WERK</span></div></li>
  <li id="OU"><div><span>OUTER</span></div></li>
  <li id="IN"><div><span>INTRA</span></div></li>
</div>
```

Comment: No está claro lo que preguntas...¿ puedes poner un ejemplo funcional de lo que has intentado? En ese código no se ve qué es `this`

Comment: Por ahí irán los tiros entonces jaja. Esperad que amplio la parte de js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que el selector del evento click está mal. Lo tienes en this pero lo que deberias poner es el elemento en el cual se especifica el evento, debería ser en el elemento `li`:

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var name = $(this).closest("li").prop("tagName");
  console.log(id+": "+name);
  console.log();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-column" id="first-column">
  <li id="WE">
    <div><span>WERK</span></div>
  </li>
  <li id="OU">
    <div><span>OUTER</span></div>
  </li>
  <li id="IN">
    <div><span>INTRA</span></div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Voy a probar eso. Pero si, tengo jquery bastante oxidado y pinta a que el this apunta al limbo.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function($) {
  $('.first-column li').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="first-column" id="first-column">
                            <li id="WE"><div><span>WERK</span></div></li>
                            <li id="OU"><div><span>OUTER</span></div></li>
                            <li id="IN"><div><span>INTRA</span></div></li>
                        </div>
```